# Pseudo code for solving equation via relaxation method

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python while learning computational physics. We have gone over the relaxation and putting in to Python.

For example:

```
def relax(v)
     return (V[i-1,j] + V[i+1,j] + V[i,j-1] + V[i,j+1]) / 4.0
```

My question is how would I use the relaxation method to solve for an equation? For example:

```
x = 1 - e^(x) ?
```

I would like to learn more about relaxation after this but right now the relaxation method is confusing me when applying it to simple math equations.

Comment: I found the answer, it would be something like : xi+1 = 1-e^(xi)  and im guessing when it converges to a point, that is my answer. How would i show that on python? Would i have to graph it and if so how would i set that up?

Comment: It'd be best if you write up the answer you found as an answer, in the box below, and then if you have more questions, post a separate followup question. But make sure to try working things out yourself first!